# Como instalar o Composer no Windows 10?

Tags: php, composer

Estou tentando instalar o composer no Windows 10, mas está aparecendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
> C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\Php\php.exe
>
> The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\Php\php.ini
>
> A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the  'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.
>
> Program Output:
> Failed loading C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.1-vc14.dll
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\php\ext\php_mysql.dll' - Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.
> in Unknown on line 0

Como podem ver, uso o VertrigoServ. Já tentei executar em modo administrador, já tentei com o 'extension_dir' comentado e não comentado.

Atualmente o arquivo php.ini está assim nesse trecho:

> ; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
>
> ; http://php.net/extension-dir
>
> ; extension_dir = "./"
>
> ; On windows:
>
> extension_dir = "ext"

Comment: da uma olhada neste questao https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913142/installing-composer-internal-error

Comment: Você tem duas versões de php na sua máquina?

Comment: Aconteceu uma vez comigo. Olha só [aqui](https://goo.gl/b4cCHP)